# Don't let closed questions keep bad tags alive

Tags: feature-request, tags, closed-questions

I was just getting rid of the [language-learning](/questions/tagged/language-learning) meta-tag, and ran into a few questions that had *only* that tag.  As you might guess, they were usually bad questions, and were often already closed.  I went with the bad solution of retagging them, so that [language-learning](/questions/tagged/language-learning) could die (RIP), but that's not really The Right Way (tm).

**Questions closed for being bad questions shouldn't keep bad tags alive to attract more bad questions to those bad tags.**

Eventually the bad questions will be automatically culled, but that's not a good solution to this problem.  Tags are globally visible, so even though no one's bothered by the presence of a bad question while it sits around waiting to be culled, its tags are ever-ready to be included on some other (probably bad) question.

I don't know how best to handle closed questions that are left tagless, but deletion might be warranted.

<sup>As an aside, if anyone's looking for other bad tags to rampage through: [exercise](/questions/tagged/exercise) 
 [practice](/questions/tagged/practice)
 [books](/questions/tagged/books)
 [programming-languages](/questions/tagged/programming-languages)
 [code-reading](/questions/tagged/code-reading) and 
 [code-examples](/questions/tagged/code-examples) are ripe for killing.</sup>

Comment: Well that's why you typically vote to delete them. Deleted questions don't keep tags alive.

Comment: @lunboks Not all of us can vote to delete them.

Answer (score 7):

Closed questions can theoretically be reopened.

If the question is bad enough that it shouldn't be reopened then you should be casting delete votes. If the "delete" link isn't visible then down-vote so that the question moves into territory where it will be automatically deleted.

If the tag is particularly egregious then just edit it out of the question.

If the question has merit then edit and vote to reopen.

Either way there's nothing extra that needs to be done.